# clojure / lisp dialect etc function result expression

Tags: clojure

Are you able to have multiple expressions in a clojure function.

Below is an example.

```
(defn side-effect-add [a b]
   (println "Doing some side effect")
   (+ 1 2)
   (+ a b)
)
```

Is something like this ok or is a function allowed to have / return the result of a single expression in the body.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you ever tried to run that in the REPL?

Comment: this is possible, but (+ 1 2) may as well not be there because it doesn't do anything but make the CPU spin

Comment: @noisesmith ... so Hotspot might even eliminate it?

Comment: I'd hope so. Only one way to find out I guess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is valid Clojure.

- Of a *sequence* of expressions/forms , the function returns the value
  of the last. Any others only have side-effects, such as `(println  ...)` above.
- A [function body](http://clojure.org/special_forms#Special%20Forms--(fn%20name?%20[params*%20]%20exprs*)) has an implicit [`do`](http://grimoire.arrdem.com/1.6.0/clojure.core/do/) to bring this about.

Comment: Btw: "A function body has an implicit do" also means that only the *last expression* will be actually returned.